# Using Prolog to Parse Grammar

Tags: parsing, prolog, grammar

I would like to use Prolog to parse the following grammar:

```
E -> E + T | E - T |T
T -> T * F | T / F | F
F -> ( E ) | number | letter
```

Here's a test case that should be true (My problem is  that it is currently coming out as false):

```
e([ 34 , *,  '(', 45, +, b, ')']).
```

i.e. `34 * (45 + b)`

And here is my attempt:

```
e(X) :- append(List1, [+ | List2], X), e(List1), t(List2).
e(X) :- append(List1, [- |List2], X), e(List1), t(List2).

t(X) :- append(List1, [* | List2], X), t(List1), f(List2).
t(X) :- append(List1, [/ | List2], X), t(List1), f(List2).

t(X) :- f(X).

f(X) :- append(['(' | List], [')'], X), e(List).


letter(X) :- member(X, [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, 
                       n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z]).
f([X]) :- number(X).
f([X]) :- letter(X).
```

Comment: Do you have a question? One omission I see is you don't have the `E -> T` case. You also need to keep clauses for the same predicate together, so, for example, `f([X]) :- ...` need to come right after your `f(X) :- ...`. You might want to look at Prolog's DCG capability, which is ideal for this kind of task.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I forgot to add my question (adding it now). When I input the expression, 34 * (45 + b), I am getting false, when it should be true. For some reason, it's still false, even after making those corrections.

Comment: You should add your exact top level interaction to the question, just edit it. No reason to add details in comments.

Comment: @user2411290 if I take your code as shown and fix both issues I mention in my comment, I get "true" when I test the example expression you gave.